# Flutter MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to check device-size always returns same wrong value in the iOS Simulator

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter-App that needs to resize elements on small screens (iPhone 5S, SE, 6S, Galaxy 5S, etc).

In order to do that I'm calling `double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`, and if that value is below `750` pixels (iPhone 6S Size) the elements get made smaller.

This works excellently on devices, but in the iOS-simulator the value is always something small (~375), no matter which simulated device it runs on. Which basically make seeing if the app works on the simulator unusable afterwards, as it always shows the "small" version.

Is there a better way to get the device-size which works with the iOS-Simulator? Or possibly other ways to adapt to the screen-size?

Comment: Your own answer is the right approach indeed. Note that in iOS simulator only, the width retrieved by MediaQuery varies as you resize the simulator window itself. This doesn't happen in Android emulator. Don't know if this is intended by the Flutter team or it's a bug(ish) behavior of the Apple's Simulator. I believe it's the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out there are "logical" pixels (which the system is outputting here) and "device" pixels, which are calculated by reading out the ratio between those two.

This is used when a "pixel" can have sub-pixels, like when the never iDevices greatly increased their actual resolution, but the pixel-counts did not get multiplied by the same factor.

```
double logicalPixelWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
double devicePixelWidth = logicalPixelWidth * devicePixelRatio;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
import 'dart:ui';
window.physicalSize.width; // This will return the physical pixels.
```